# when to stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the demo below. On click of next i scroll it but i want to hide next when end has reached. How do i know when to stop scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/77kJp/2/

JS

```
$("span").click(function(){ 
    $('span').after('<br />'+$( "div.demo" )[0].scrollWidth+'-'+$( "div.demo" ).scrollLeft() + '-'+$( "div.demo p" )[0].scrollWidth );
    $( "div.demo" ).animate({
        scrollLeft: $( "div.demo" ).scrollLeft() + 800
    });
});
```

ps: 800 in demo is just for ease

Answer (score 0):

run a function after animation complete like this 
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$('selector').animate(
{
    right : "100px", 
}, 500,
function() {
    $('selector').hide(); // this will run after the animation is complete 
}
);
```

Comment: but how do i know when to hide

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/77kJp/3/  it will hide once the animation is done in your case it will hide once you scroll to your destination.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `scroll()` event listener. Whenever your `demo` div is scrolled, check its current position from the left, and if it's greater than a certain threshold, hide your span that says 'next'

Add this JS after your `$("span").click()` code:

```
var leftPos;
$(".demo").scroll(function(event){
    leftPos = $(".demo").scrollLeft();
    if(leftPos > 700){
        $("span").hide();
    }else{
        $("span").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Then don't hardcode 700, and edit the number as you deem necessary.

Comment: i mean on i want to hide run only when end is reached

Comment: Then use `$(".demo").width();` to get the maximum position it can reach. Once `leftPos == $(".demo").width()` then you can hide it.

Comment: Actually, it may need to be `leftPos == $(".demo").width()-1` I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: its not thats why i asked

Comment: I'm sorry, your responses make it difficult to understand why it's not working. I don't think I can help you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback function of animate

```
$("span").click(function(){ 
        $('span').after('<br />'+$( "div.demo" )[0].scrollWidth+'-'+$( "div.demo" ).scrollLeft() + '-'+$( "div.demo p" )[0].scrollWidth );
        $( "div.demo" ).animate({
            scrollLeft: $( "div.demo" ).scrollLeft() + 800
        },function() {
    $('span').hide();
  });
    });
```

Comment: 800 is just for easy demo in my example. This will hide after each click

Comment: Check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aqN3/1/).
i guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: This is what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/5aqN3/2/... It has not reached end but still hides